# Install rtl8188etv/rtl8188eu driver on Orange-Pi

Tags: kernel, wifi, drivers

I'm trying to install the wifi driver on Orange-Pi board.
The real chip is **rtl8188etv** but the driver is the same.

1. I have compiled 3.4.105+ Kernel to have the headers:

   ```
   mkdir /home/orangepi/linux-kernel-3.4.105
   cd /home/orangepi/linux-kernel-3.4.105
   git clone https://github.com/silentcreek/bananapi-kernel --depth 1
   cd bananapi-kernel
   make sun7i_defconfig
   make menuconfig                  # esc-esc to exit
   make -j2 uImage modules          # ~ 2.5h working
   sudo make modules_install
   sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot
   sudo cp arch/arm/boot/uImage /boot
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. I have compiled [rtl8188eu driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu) like this:

   ```
   make all
   sudo make install
   ```

The compilations shows no errors.

**But** the wifi chip is not seen:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
```

However, all informations are here:

```
$ uname -r
3.4.105+

$sudo modprobe 8188eu
# no errors

$lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cpufreq_stats           5901  0 
cpufreq_userspace       3294  0 
cpufreq_conservative     5966  0 
cpufreq_powersave       1197  0 
8188eu                731474  0 
8021q                  18594  0 
garp                    6114  1 8021q
stp                     1993  1 garp
llc                     5491  2 stp,garp

$ modinfo 8188eu
filename:       /lib/modules/3.4.105+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
version:        v4.1.4_6773.20130222
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     3628DD5717A5BF3727CD195
alias:          usb:v056Ep4008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3311d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p3310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0076d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.4.105+ SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_cbw40_enable:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_fw_iol:FW IOL (int)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (1-9) (default 1) (int)

$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:45:08:42:54:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: tunl0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0


orangepi@orangepi:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:45:08:42:54:c5  
          inet adr:192.168.2.4  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::45:8ff:fe42:54c5/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          RX bytes:1369227 (1.3 MiB)  TX bytes:899008 (877.9 KiB)
          Interruption:117 Adresse de base:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          RX bytes:174800 (170.7 KiB)  TX bytes:174800 (170.7 KiB)

tunl0     Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And of course, `iwconfig` do not see nothing at all. What I have missed?

Comment: Just to be sure: after loading the module with `modprobe`, does it appear in `lsmod`?

Comment: Yes I see it, I will update my question to show `lsmod`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `modinfo 8188eu` can be useful ? There's a lot of informations..

Comment: Please provide whatever you think could be necessary :) Right now, all I can think about is that the module might just be buggy (hopefully, it logs its failures somewhere).

Comment: The log, like `dmesg | tail -50`, or other ?

Comment: **Is this actually a USB wifi adapter you have attached?** That board has built-in wifi which may *or may not* use the USB bus. If it is a real USB adapter, it doesn't matter whether you have the driver installed or not, it should still show up via `lsusb`.  If not, something is wrong or broken and you are probably out of luck.

Comment: It's the internal wifi module (onboard), I think connected in USB, because `lspci` does not have entry, and `lshw` has just ethernet interface.

Comment: Doesn't someone have this *documented somewhere* then?  You haven't said why you think it is not working.  What does `ip link` or `ifconfig -a` show?  PCI seems more likely, but if none of these utilities list it...that's not good.

Comment: I'm connected with ethernet actually but I edit my question to show you the results

Comment: I think you should contact the Orange Pi people and ask them about this.  Have you tried [their forum](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php)?  Someone can at least tell you **which bus it is on.**

Comment: Yes, I will maybe ask them (I have already post several questions) but I thought post here may have more chance to be solved ;)
Orange is very new, so I think I must wait for a special kernel to use wifi... It does not matter. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the configuration is good but the module must be activate in a configuration file, load before the kernel: http://wiki.lemaker.org/Banana_Pi_Fex_Configuration
Orange Pi uses the same file.